# How to sort an Iterable without creating intermediate Seq?

Tags: scala

I have a Map of `String -> Foo` and I want to get a sorted collection of Foos by Foo.priority:

```
fooMap.collect { case (k, f) if k.startWith("F") => f }.toSeq.sortBy(_.priority)
```

How can I avoid the intermediate `toSeq`? Can I create a new collection and insert by the ordering? Maybe something like:

```
fooMap.collect { case (k, f) if k.startWith("F") => f }.to[Seq](orderedCanBuildFrom) //does not work
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? What is the problem with converting to a suitable collection type before sorting?

Comment: @Tim Performance concerns. We have a very large collection to sort, and very tight memory allocation and latency requirement.

Comment: What is type of **priority**? Integer?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Ya it is an Int

Comment: @texasbruce Can it take any value or only the limited set (like [1,2,3..100])? Maybe you should go for counting sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you are tight on memory and latency, try this

```
fooMap.view.filter(_._1.startsWith("F")).map(_._2).toSeq.sortBy(_.priority)
```

Otherwise consider buying more memory and/or speed :).

Answer (score 4):

You can't sort an `Iterable` directly, and the insertion sort that you describe is going to be very slow for large collections.

The best option is probably to convert to `Array` and use the [scala.util.sorting](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Sorting$.html) package which provides in-place sorting of `Array`s.

Answer (score 1):

For Scala 2.12 and below, I use a custom CanBuildFrom to allow map/collect to transform into a different collection type. `scala.collection.breakOut` does this automatically:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

fooMap.collect[Foo, Seq[Foo]]  { 
  case (k, f) if k.startWith("F") => f
}(breakOut).sortBy(_.priority)
```

For Scala 2.13 and above, since `CanBuildFrom` and `breakOut` is no longer available and `View`s are more reliable, I would use a view as stated in @volty-de-qua 's answer, since only from 2.13 that `collection.Views have been vastly simplified and should now work reliably.`